# How to Pass value along with file upload through webclient C#

Tags: c#, .net

Now currently uploading a file only through below code .. what actually looking is need to send a value "myValue" too how can i achieve this

```
      string message, title, defaultValue;
        string myValue;
     
        message = "Enter Image name please";
     
        title = "Image name";
         
        defaultValue = "1";
            myValue =Interaction.InputBox(message, title, defaultValue,100,100);
using (System.Net.WebClient Client = new System.Net.WebClient())
        {
            Client.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "binary/octet-stream");
            Client.Headers.Add("SESSION-KEY", App.Session_Key);

        try
        {
            byte[] result = Client.UploadFile(Screenshot.Properties.Resources.APIURL + "Upload.php", "POST", "temp.png");
```

here i need to send "myValue " too while file upload

Comment: It is quite unclear what you want to achieve - please read duplicate I selected and see if that aligns with what you are asking, than [edit] the question if it needs to be re-opened. At very least clarify what server is expecting as request.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov now works for file upload but iam looking how to pass a string to client.uploadfile()

like Client.UploadFile(url, "POST", "temp.png","new value");